# Как с клиентской части передать токен с $_GET запросом. Сделать выборку по пользователю. Полученные данные вывести в формате JSON

Tags: php

```
Всем привет. Интересует вопрос "Как с клиентской части передать токен с $_GET запросом. Сделать выборку по пользователю. Полученные данные вывести в формате JSON"

 

 $sql = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE
 accessToken='$token'");
 if ($sql_check->num_rows > 0) {
     echo json_encode(["status" => false]); } else {
     $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
     $token = md5($hashed_password);
 
     $connection->query("INSERT INTO `users1` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`, `accessToken`) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname',
 '$email', '$hashed_password', '$token')");
```

Comment: Зачем плодить  один и тот же вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426089/Получение-данных-по-токену-php-mysql решали бы там. В вашем случае додумывать много приходится. Сейчас открылось, что token из `$_GET` поступает. Кусок кода вы откуда выдернули? вы его хотите заменить? насколько я понял, передаются параметры пасворд, емейл и т.д. И теперь в $_GET содержится ваш токен?

Comment: Кусок с запросом token из $_GET, не было. Его нужно добавить. Всё, что связанно с Токеном, я не могу понять. И тут подробно расписал, что нужно.

Comment: Начнем издалека. Массив $_GET формирует по запросу клиента..Что-бы в нем на сервере появились данные с клиента надо в строке запроса указать, например, урл?accessToken=токен..далее вам нужно найти место где идет обработка запроса на сервере..что-бы можно было вставить туда код. Вы такое место знаете? Вот этот кусок откуда выдернут? Вы хотите изменений именно этого участка кода на сервере?

Comment: Нужно выбрать все элемента, где accessToken = которому мы передали. Эти полученные данные надо вывести в формате JSON. Это весь кусок кода, что я прикрепил, он относится к Токену, пусть даже косвенно, других кусков нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

плохо, что я потестить не могу решение. Попробуйте такой код или его понять и подправить под ваши нужды, в нем все что вам нужно есть:

```
$token=$_GET['accessToken'];    
$sql = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE
 accessToken='$token'");
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
} 
if ($sql_check->num_rows > 0) {
     echo json_encode(["status" => false]); } else {
     $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
     $token = md5($hashed_password);
 
     $connection->query("INSERT INTO `users1` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`, `accessToken`) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname',
 '$email', '$hashed_password', '$token')");
```

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо